# Modernizr wiping previous added html classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr in rails project. I'm also setting some classes for IE8 on the html tag

/[if IE 8]
  %html{class:'ie8 oldie'}

When I add Modernizr to the mix it removes the classes ie8 oldie and replaces it with js. 
How can I stop it doing this. Really what it should do is append it and not remove my previously added ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the order you are doing things?

I'm doing the same thing in Joomla, with the following:

**HTML**

```
<?php  
....
$doc->addScript($tpath.'/js/modernizr.js');    
...
?>  

<!doctype html>
...
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8 oldie" <![endif]-->
...
```

and if I access the page in IE8, the page source is:

```
<html class="ie8 oldie js ...">
```

Good luck!